# Find $T,S: V \to V$ be two linear transformations such that $KetT=KerS \neq0$ and $ImT=ImS$ but $T\neq S$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $ >1$

Let $T,S: V \to V$ be two linear transformations such that $KerT=KerS \neq0$ and $ImT=ImS$ but $T\neq S$

Find such $T,S$.

My thoughts:

To take $T=A_V$, $S=B_V$, $B=2A$. But as if I don't anything about $V$, I cannot guarantee that I can even multiply $A$ by $v$

Comment: You do not impose any restriction on the base field. The result is not true in the case of a $2$-dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ of $2$ elements. That's the only counterexample, though, although @Abishanka Saha's proof needs tweaking in the case of $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a basis for $V$ to be $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$, where $n\geq 2$. Now let $T(v_1)=v_1$ and $T(v_i)=0$ for all $i\ge 2$. Also let $S(v_1)=cv_1$for some scalar $c\neq0,1$, and $S(v_i)=0$ for all $i\ge 2$.

Comment: I think you also need $c\not= 0$ here.

Comment: Yep you are right.

Comment: And you can't find such a $c$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$ if that's the field, and so you're stuck. If $n>2$ I think that it's easier to let $S$ and $T$ kill $v_1$ and to permute the other basis elements in different ways.

Comment: What different ways do you suggest?

Comment: $S$ fixes the lot, $T$ swaps two and fixes the others: possible if $n>2$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $V=\Bbb{R}^2$ and the matrix of $T$ and $S$ be respectively $$M_{T}=\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{matrix}\right),~~M_{S}=\left(\begin{matrix}2&0\\ 0&0\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a more general proof without knowing what V is.